# Is there 'file path' for files in Google Drive SDK v2 (Android)?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In my Google Drive (in browser f.e.) i can see file structure - files and folders. In Drive SDK v2 (Android) i can't see any `path` property for the file. So how can i insert file in specific folder since `insert()` method does not have `path` parameter? how can i check file existence in specific folder and so on? what does it mean the file can have few parents?

Answer (score 1):

Use the parents property which provides an array of parent 'folders" for any given file. This is both how you add a file to a folder and also query which folder a file is in.

A file can be in more than one folder simply by having multiple parents.

Be careful that if you delete a folder, all of the files in that folder will be deleted, even if they also exist in other folders.

Comment: so how can i mkdirs() and create file in /a/b/c/d/file? Should i create folders a,b,c,d one-by-one with previous one as a parent?

Comment: Exactly. When you create a, the response from Drive will include its ID. You will use that as the parent id for b, and so on.

Comment: It seems to be too compicated. Then how can i check file /a/b/c/d/file exists?

Comment: How can i get files in root folder? it's request with no Q (as it does not contain parents), but it returns all the files on drive, right?

Comment: the root folder has an id of "root". so just check if root is in parents. remember that a file can have more than one parent, so can be in root and in a and in b. your app will normally cache the id of important golfers and v test of the cached id is in the parents.

Comment: "golfers" is of course "folders" for those that don't speak autocorrectish

Comment: using google drive sdk is real pain as i have to implement synchronizing too (i'm learning example app). now cache parent ids too.. dropbox sdk is muuuuuuch better if talking about working with files with auto sync only