# How can I get the exact path of the file in my googledrive as if it was stored in FTP?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use it for a launcher for my game.
In order to compare files to know their versions, I need to access them the same way I do locally ( via their path, example: myGame\someFolder\someFile.SomeExtension  ).

Comment: Google drive isn't an FTP server its a webservice so its going to be a URL to download a file.

Comment: And yet you can see a file parents ids and from their to check their name and see if it fits the folders names but this is so much messing around.
There got to be a more straight forward approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there 'file path' for files in Google Drive SDK v2 (Android)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566415/is-there-file-path-for-files-in-google-drive-sdk-v2-android)

Comment: a simple google search shows its a duplicate. search google for: drive file path site:stackoverflow.com